# Markdown to .doc or .rtf

Tags: macos, ms-office, markdown

I'm interested in using a variation of Markdown for my work, but my target format is Word files (this is what my clients use, it's non-negotiable). Most implementations of Markdown would leave me with a circuitous route at best to get a Word file.

Perhaps more importantly, I'd want to be able to format things like footnotes/endnotes, which don't have any representation in Markdown or Multimarkdown, as far as I know.

Is there anything like this out there? Basically a flavor of Markdown oriented toward print rather than the screen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/):

```
pandoc -f markdown -t docx file.md -o file.docx
```

One advantage compared to `textutil` is that the output uses paragraph styles. You can also use styles from an existing file with `--reference-docx file.docx`.

Answer (score 6):

John Gruber, one of the two inventors of Markdown, uses footnotes fairly extensively on [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net); to see his raw (pre-Markdown) formatting, append `.text` to one of his urls, like this: http://daringfireball.net/2012/07/this_ipad_mini_thing.text.

As far as converting Markdown to RTF, `textutil` is your friend. You can pipe the output of the `Markdown.pl` command to `textutil` like so:

```
/usr/local/bin/Markdown.pl | /usr/bin/textutil -stdin -stdout -format html -convert rtf | pbcopy # or whatever else you want to do with it
```

Instead of piping to pbcopy (which puts the rich text on the clipboard), you could `>` it to a .rtf file, or whatever else your workflow dictates.

Comment: `textutil` is handy!

Comment: Download page for Markdown.pl : [https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)

Answer (score 0):

iA Writer offers formatted Word (.docx) to Markdown import and export: [iAWriter.com](http://iawriter.com/mac)

[image: Word to Markdown Import and Export]